# Join SQL tables using a Column containing JSON

Tags: sql

Is it possible to join 2 tables on a normal vchar column and a column containing json stored as a string?
Table 1 contains an ID column
Table 2 contains a Log column which contains the value "Table1ID" within a json string

| ID | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| T1A | foo |
| T1B | foo |

| ID | Log |
| --- | --- |
| T2A | {"Table1Id": "T1A","User": "Terry Dactil"} |
| T2B | {"Table1IB": "T1B","User": "Sherman Tank"} |

Looking to join table 1 on Id to table 2 Log using the Table1ID json data
I could use a temp table but there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: Could you post the tables?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (postgres, mysql, microsoft sql server, oracle, teradata, snowflake)? Can you share sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out in the end.

```
Select * 
From Table1 a 
    JOIN Table2 b on a.Id = JSON_VALUE(b.[Log],'$.Table1Id')
```